# How to change color of selected element in eclipse (for Java)?

Tags: java

The color is really bright and i just want to change it to a light color

[image]

Comment: This is not a code question, and probably will be downvoted soon.

Comment: Would it be easier to tape in google? Look here for example: https://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-change-eclipse-theme/